# Aurelia start setRoot gives the error No applicationHost was specified

Tags: javascript, typescript, aurelia, codesandbox

Using the following code:

```
import { Aurelia } from "aurelia-framework";

export async function configure(aurelia) {
  aurelia.use.standardConfiguration().developmentLogging();

  await aurelia
    .start()
    .then(a => a.setRoot())
    //.then(a => a.setRoot("app.js", document.body))
    .catch(ex => {
      document.body.textContent = `Bootstrap error: ${ex}`;
    });
}
```

I get this error:

> Bootstrap error: Error: No applicationHost was specified.

If I switch to use `.then(a => a.setRoot("app.js", document.body))` instead of `.then(a => a.setRoot())` everything works.

In Aurelias own quick start guide they use the following code:

```
import {Aurelia} from 'aurelia-framework';

export function configure(aurelia: Aurelia) {
    aurelia.use.basicConfiguration();
    aurelia.start().then(() => aurelia.setRoot());
}
```

If i switch to `use.basicConfiguration` in my code I still get the same error.

https://aurelia.io/docs/tutorials/creating-a-todo-app#getting-ready-to-render

Codesandbox to reproduce:

https://codesandbox.io/s/0x4wvlly90

Comment: The code as written would seem correct to me. I believe the empty call to `setRoot` doesn't work when using Webpack, as Webpack needs you to be specific about what modules need to be loaded. If I had to guess, I'd guess that there is a similar issue with how our CodeSandbox "loader" works.

Comment: @AshleyGrant I suspected the "CodeSandbox loader" as well at first. However I tested with Aurelia Script and got the exact same result. https://codesandbox.io/s/lp342n59w7 Modified code from https://aurelia.io/blog/2018/11/04/aurelia-2018-q3-report/.

Answer (score 0):

In automatic bootstrapping, `aurelia-bootstrapper` detects elements with `aurelia-app` attribute, and based on the value specified, will load the main entry to bootstrap with the information about which elements host those `aurelia-app` attributes. That's why you can do `setRoot()` without any arguments. First argument is `app.js`, and the second argument is automatically supplied by the above detection.

When you do manually bootstrapping like in the question code block, there is no information about root, thus the error as you saw. So it's correct, and standard way to do it that you are supplying the 2nd parameter.

Comment: I tried setting `<body aurelia-app="app.js">` in both examples but I still get the same error. See `Codesandbox`. https://codesandbox.io/s/lp342n59w7 and https://codesandbox.io/s/0x4wvlly90

Comment: In traditional setup, the entry of your app is `aurelia-bootstrapper`, it is responsible for finding elements with attribute: `aurelia-app` or `data-aurelia-app` and bootstrap based on the value of those attributes. What you have in those sandbox is different, you are not using the `aurelia-bootstrapper` to startup the app, instead you are starting with just a few simple line of JS.